# Respecting alternating row coloring when coloring cells in a DataGridView

Tags: c#, datagridview, colors, rows, alternating

Similar to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1999331/c-sharp-coloring-the-same-values-in-row-of-datagridview) I'm trying to color individual cells in a DataGridView in c#.  I'd like to support coloration for alternating rows though.  My view does toggle row visibility and allows sorting, so I can't just use Index mod 2 to figure out which color to use.  Is there any way to do this?

Also, this is for a VSTO plug-in to MS Project, so I don't believe the (very nice) css solutions are applicable.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

css is the best way to do it.

set CssClass="gridview"

then in css

```
  .gridview td :even
  {
  background-color: #CCC;
   }

    .gridview td :odd
   {
     background-color: #fff;
     }
```

Comment: Sorry, I should have mentioned... this is a VSTO add-in for Project 2010, and I haven't seen a way to apply css to the form or the widgets inside.  Is there a way?

Thanks for the reply!